# Changing state of navbar after user signs up in Vue.js and Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working on a simple Vue.js app, in which an user can sign up and log in. For the login and sign up operation I'm working with Firebase Authentication. So far I've managed to make the user successfully log in and change the navbar state: when the user is logged out, it displays 2 buttons: one login button, and the other is a sign up button. When the user signs in, these buttons are replaced by the user's name and an option to sign out.
The problem is with the sign up option: right after filling up the form and pressing submit, the navbar state is altered, the sign out option shows up, but no username is displayed. I want to either display the user's name as well as the sign out button, or for the application to not log in right after the user signs up. Is there a way to do so?

Sign up form script:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

export default {
  name: 'Sign-Up',
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        errors: [],
        name: "",
        email: "",
        username: "",
        password: ""
      },
      error: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.email, this.form.password)
        .then(data => {
          data.user
            .updateProfile({
              displayName: this.form.name
            })
            .then(() => {})
            .then(this.$router.replace({ name: "Profile" }))
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.error = err.message;
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Navbar

```
        <template v-if="user.loggedIn">
          <ul class="nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
            <li style="margin-top: 0.5em;"><router-link to="/Dashboard" class="nav-link px-2">Hello, {{user.data.displayName}}</router-link></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2" @click.prevent="signOut"><button type="button" class="btn poke-secondary me-2">Sign out</button></a></li>
          </ul>
        </template>
        <template v-else>
          <div class="col-md-3 text-end px-2">
            <router-link to="/login"><button type="button" class="btn poke-secondary me-2">Login</button></router-link>
            <router-link to="/signup"><button type="button" class="btn poke-secondary">Sign Up</button></router-link>
          </div>
        </template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
export default {
  name: "Header",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      user: "user"
    })
  },
  methods: {
    signOut() {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signOut()
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.replace({
            name: "Home"
          });
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

store.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: {
      loggedIn: false,
      data: null
    }
  },
  getters: {
    user(state){
      return state.user
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_LOGGED_IN(state, value) {
      state.user.loggedIn = value;
    },
    SET_USER(state, data) {
      state.user.data = data;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchUser({ commit }, user) {
      commit("SET_LOGGED_IN", user !== null);
      if (user) {
        commit("SET_USER", {
          displayName: user.displayName,
          email: user.email
        });
      } else {
        commit("SET_USER", null);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You will probably want to return a promise that resolve when the user data is fully available. The Firebase response is asynchronous, so it might not be immediately available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to either display the user's name as well as the sign out
> button, **or for the application to not log in right after the user
> signs up**. Is there a way to do so?

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword), with the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method, "on successful creation of the user account, this user will also be signed in to your application".

So there is no way to avoid the user being signed in "right after the user signs up". Your problem comes form the fact the `updateProfile()` method is asynchronous: there is a small delay before `displayName` is updated. You should handle this case, by, for example, displaying the `Hello, {{user.data.displayName}}` string and the "Sign Out" button only when `displayName` is not null.

Answer (score 1):

As @Renaud explained the user will be logged in right after the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method is resolved rendering that div only when `displayName` is not null which can be done by `v-if="user.data.displayName !== null"`.

An alternative would be to use a [Cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions) to create new users if you really don't want that delay in rendering username. As the users are created using [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) in the cloud function they won't be logged in on the client. A simple callable function for the same would be:

```js
exports.createNewUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const {email, password, displayName} = data
  
  return admin.auth().createUser({ email, password, displayName }).then((userRecord) => {
    console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
    return {data: userRecord.uid}
  }) 
});
```

This function will create a new user with provided credentials along with username. You can call this function from your Vue app as follows:

```js
methods: {
  submit() {
    const createUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createNewUser');
    createNewUser({ 
      email: this.form.email, 
      password: this.form.password,
      displayName: this.form.name
    }).then((result) => {
      const result = result.data;

      // Manually sign in user now
      // signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.email, this.form.password)
    });
  }
}
```